# Inner product and adjoint mapping in matrices

Tags: matrices, inner-products, trace, adjoint-operators

Let $\mathcal{A}_1:S^n \to S^n$ be defined by $\mathcal{A}_1(P)=-(A^*P+PA)$.   How can I find $\mathcal{A}_1^{adj} (Z)$, where $\mathcal{A}_1^{adj}:S^n \to S^n$?

Comment: Can you please add more information, define the various notations?

Comment: $S^n$ denotes the set of Hermitian $n×n$ matrices, given by $\langle A, B\rangle_{S^n} =TrA^*B=TrAB$.

Comment: $S$ is a space of block diagonal Hermitian matrices and $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: $\mathcal{A}:V\to S $ is a linear mapping and $\mathcal{A}^{adj}$ is the adjoint mapping of $\mathcal{A} $. That is, $\mathcal{A}^{adj}:S\to V$such that for all $x\in V$ and $Z\in S, \ \langle \mathcal{A}(x), Z\rangle_S= \langle x, \mathcal{A}^{adj}(Z) \rangle_V$

Comment: I wrote all information. How is solve of my problem?

Comment: Rewrite $\langle \mathcal -(A^\ast X+XA),Y\rangle$ as $\langle X,\cdots\rangle$ where the expression in the ellipses depends only on $Y$ and $A$.

Comment: Using cyclicity of the trace for example. By the way you can edit the question directly using the edit button, rather than adding additional information in the comment.